# How to web scrape table element using rvest?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am looking to scrape data from this [carrier link](https://www.aaacooper.com/pwb/Transit/ProTrackResults.aspx?ProNum=241939875&AllAccounts=true), I am using the rvest package in R and ive scraped some of the top information in the webpage by using this code below:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.aaacooper.com/pwb/Transit/ProTrackResults.aspx?ProNum=241939875&AllAccounts=true"
page <- read_html(url)

# Extract the table on the page
table <- page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[2]] %>% html_table()

# Print the table
View(table)
```

Which yields this information:
[image: pic1]

However, I am looking to retrieve the information from the Tracing Information table in a tabular format instead:
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a mundate method:

```r
library(rvest)
sess <- session("https://www.aaacooper.com/pwb/Transit/ProTrackResults.aspx?ProNum=241939875&AllAccounts=true")
html_table(sess)[[9]]
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#    Date       Time  Description                                               
#    <chr>      <chr> <chr>                                                     
#  1 2022-06-24 13:02 Delivered To Consignee In BRADENTON, FL                   
#  2 2022-06-24 04:22 Shipment arrived at destination Service Center   TAMPA, FL
#  3 2022-06-24 03:02 Shipment departed ORLANDO Service Center                  
#  4 2022-06-23 06:34 Shipment arrived at ORLANDO Service Center                
#  5 2022-06-22 22:54 Shipment departed DOTHAN Service Center                   
#  6 2022-06-21 22:52 Shipment arrived at DOTHAN Service Center                 
#  7 2022-06-21 10:36 Shipment departed HOUSTON Service Center                  
#  8 2022-06-21 03:15 Shipment arrived at HOUSTON Service Center                
#  9 2022-06-20 19:59 Shipment departed WESLACO Service Center                  
# 10 2022-06-20 12:21 Shipment Picked Up From Shipper In WESLACO, TX
```

The use of `[[9]]` was based on looking at all tables returned by `html_table()`, there's nothing guaranteeing that number will persist.

A better method of finding a table is by looking for specific attributes/headers/names/ids, best found using the [SelectorGadget](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/articles/selectorgadget.html).

A slightly more detailed look at the URL page reveals that the *parent* node of that table has `class="tracingInformation"`, indicating we can do this:

```r
html_element(sess, ".tracingInformation") %>%
  html_children() %>%
  html_table()
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#    Date       Time  Description                                               
#    <chr>      <chr> <chr>                                                     
#  1 2022-06-24 13:02 Delivered To Consignee In BRADENTON, FL                   
#  2 2022-06-24 04:22 Shipment arrived at destination Service Center   TAMPA, FL
#  3 2022-06-24 03:02 Shipment departed ORLANDO Service Center                  
#  4 2022-06-23 06:34 Shipment arrived at ORLANDO Service Center                
#  5 2022-06-22 22:54 Shipment departed DOTHAN Service Center                   
#  6 2022-06-21 22:52 Shipment arrived at DOTHAN Service Center                 
#  7 2022-06-21 10:36 Shipment departed HOUSTON Service Center                  
#  8 2022-06-21 03:15 Shipment arrived at HOUSTON Service Center                
#  9 2022-06-20 19:59 Shipment departed WESLACO Service Center                  
# 10 2022-06-20 12:21 Shipment Picked Up From Shipper In WESLACO, TX
```

The walkthrough on how I found that. I'm using Firefox, I'm confident other browser have the same or very similar keys/tabs/names.

1. Open that url in a browser.
2. Once loaded, hit `F12` (or whatever key enters the browser's dev console).
3. Select "Pick an element" and select a cell in the table you want. (In FF, this is a small button to the left of "Inspector".)
4. Find the first reference to `<table>` above the cell. If this doesn't have an unambiguous `id=` or `class=` (as in this example, I thought `id="AAACooperMasterPage_bodyContent_grdViewTraceInfo"` was a bit obscure/automated), go up a little higher until you find a clear `id=` or `class=`. In this case, I found that the table we want is encased in another table with `class="tracingInformation"`.
5. Use that in `html_element(..)`.

Comment: thanks, what does the [[9]] signify?

Comment: It means the ninth element in the list of table-like-things found in that document.

Comment: if its not too much to ask, is it possible you can share where that 9th element is in the web page elements, I went through myself and I wasn't sure how to determine it was the 9th element

Comment: ah I see your updated answer